# What exactly is the diffference between Route53 Internal vs External.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Please excuse my ignorance, but can someone provide me with a concrete example of how/why I would use one instead of the other. I'm not asking out of the blue, I have done significant research, but the internal options makes no sense whatsoever to me.

[Best doco i could find on the subject](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/route-53-update-private-dns-more)

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious application is split horizon DNS, as the document says. Suppose you have some service on the hostname service.example.com, running in AWS, that is accessed both by your own AWS instances and also by external users. You want DNS calls for service.example.com from inside your AWS environment to return its private IP address while DNS calls from outside your environment for the same hostname should return its public IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Mike's answer is 100% correct.

I also want to add a case where you may want to have some DNS entries available internal to your application only.

For example, you may use an RDS database internally.

You could have an internal Route 53 hosted zone setup to have `rds.example.com` resolve to a CNAME of your RDS endpoint.

However, externally, `rds.example.com` does not exist because the public should not know about it.

So "split horizon" is one example, but also internal infrastructure privacy is another example.

Comment: Another good reason is the microservices web development paradigm.  While you will have many external facing services, you may have lots of 'internal' services that shouldn't be exposed to the public.